# How can I access a field during migration which is not in django model but available in databse

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I have a user model like this:

**User(name, photo_id, age)**

Now I want want to remove the field photo_id from the model as I want to create a new model:

**Photo(user, photo_id)**

In the above Photo model user is a foreign key to User table.

But before removing the field I want to copy all existing photo_id to new table.

So I created three migrations. 
1. Create a model Photo.
2. Copy the data from User to Photo.
3. Delete the field photo_id from User.

The problem is that During the second migration while I am trying to access the photo_id field for copying the data. I am not able to access the field because it is removed from the model.

But the field is there is the database.

So can anyone help me here, how I copy the fields data before removing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your migration use `apps.get_model`, instead of importing the model directly.

```
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("myapp", "User")
    for user in User.objects.all()
        print(user.photo_id)
```

This is a historical version of the model, that will have the `photo_id` field.

See the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) for more info.